# How to handle incompatible dependencies in Nuget's? Can I exclude a dependency on install?

Tags: visual-studio, dependencies, reference, nuget

I installed a Nuget on top of an application. The Nuget had a dependency to a newer version of a 3rd party dll than the base application, and now the base application cannot run because of this. How to take care of that? Is this a sign that either the Nuget or the base application violates good principles?

Afaiu the base application requires an exact version of the 3rd party dll (and the Nuget requires a later version).

Is the only way to recompile the base application with updated refs - or recompile the Nuget with ref to the older dll version?

A possible workaround could be to install the Nuget withouth automatically installing the newer version of the 3rd party dll, but I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Do you mean that you used NuGet to download a library for your base application, and that lib had a dependency on a newer version of another lib (call it 'lib3') than required by the base application?  Can I guess that 'lib3' is log4net, and the disagreement is between 1.2.9 and 1.2.10?

Comment: Yep like that, nah it was actually sqlce4, but the problem should occur for any 3rd party dll in a situation like this I guess (?)

Comment: One further clarification, I'm assuming you have no control over the "base application" that you're working with here?

Comment: I will probably ask them to do so. But at the same time this is a general question and I'm wanting to know the options / dead ends here. Thanks for asking clarifying questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's kludgey, but I would install the older version of the library that the base application requires to the GAC.  This isn't ideal, and will have to be accounted for in your installation scenario, but the GAC does allow multiple versions of the same library to be referenced.

Comment: Ah, thanks, solved my problem. After tweeting about it, I also got another suggestion - to but the dll's in different bins (I didn't try that one though).